# ArrayAdapter won't update after first suggestion with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, notifydatasetchanged

I try to use `AutoCompleteTextView` with `ArrayAdapter`. everything works correctly before first try to use `AutoCompleteTextView`. after the first try, just `AutoCompleteTextView` shows the last selection (and in this case your first try with `AutoCompleteView`). I think with `clear()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` must be ok but after `clear()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` still I have problem. I search for the same question and everything was same but still have problem

this is my adapter:

```
class CityAutoCompleteAdapter(
    context: Context,
    cityList: ArrayList<CityModel>
) : ArrayAdapter<CityModel>(context, 0, cityList) {

    var cityListFull: ArrayList<CityModel> = cityList

    private var cityFilter: Filter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

            val results = FilterResults()
            val suggestions: ArrayList<CityModel> = arrayListOf()

            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                suggestions.addAll(cityListFull)
            } else {
                val filterPattern: String = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim()

                for (item in cityListFull) {
                    if (item.cityName.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        suggestions.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = suggestions
            results.count = suggestions.size

            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {


            if (results != null) {
                //@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                addAll(results.values as? List<CityModel> ?: cityListFull)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        }

        override fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any?): CharSequence {
            val result = resultValue as CityModel
            return result.cityName
        }
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return cityFilter
    }


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        var newConvertView = convertView

        if (convertView == null) {
            newConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.simple_auto_complete_item, parent, false
            )
        }

        val txtAutoCompleteCityName: TextView =
            newConvertView?.findViewById(R.id.txtAutoCompleteLabel) ?: TextView(context)

        val cityItem: CityModel? = getItem(position)

        if (cityItem != null) {
            txtAutoCompleteCityName.text = cityItem.cityName
        }

        return newConvertView!!
    }
}
```

and this is my class where I used AutoCompleteView:

```
 cityAdapter = result.success()?.let {
                    CityAutoCompleteAdapter(
                        requireContext(),
                        it
                    )
                }

                binding.layoutFragmentPickupSender.layoutBottomSheetSender.autoAddSenderStateCity.setAdapter(cityAdapter)
                cityAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()


    binding.layoutFragmentPickupSender.layoutBottomSheetSender.autoAddSenderStateCity.onItemClickListener =
            OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, pos, id -> //this is the way to find selected object/item
                selectedCity = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos) as CityModel
                cityAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

may please guide me where I make a mistake?

Comment: I have tried. Its' hard to recurrent your code. Can you make it simple and runnable or make a repo?

Comment: I try to implement this adapter for AutoCompleteTextView `https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/custom-autocompletetextview/part-2-adapter` with kotlin. may please guide me

Comment: Why not try android studio convert java to kotlin util?

Comment: when try to convert to kotlin in android studio adapter code I got a problem in this section: `addAll(results.values as List<*>)` with this error: `following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun addAll(p0: (MutableCollection<out CityModel?>..Collection<CityModel?>)): Unit defined in com.chaparnet.chapar.views.pickup.CityAutoCompleteAdapter
public open fun addAll(vararg p0: CityModel?): Unit defined in com.chaparnet.chapar.views.pickup.CityAutoCompleteAdapter`

Comment: You refered post, code is not complete. How about modify it to              addAll(results.values as MutableList<CountryItem?>)

Comment: yes, I try this one and after this, I have this warning: ` addAll(results.values as MutableList<CountryItem?>` but with this convert to Kotlin I have the same issue. the first time everything works perfectly as I except, in the second time I have just last Item selected and in the third time I have nothing. I don't know where but I guess somewhere probably after first run I delete list in the adapter. according to the breakpoint in the second time, cityListFull is empty as I check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215461/discussion-between-mehrdad-dolatkhah-and-chuanhang-gu).